# eclipse - how to access or install an xml "aware" editor

Tags: xml, eclipse, editor

After installing Eclipse SDK Version 4.2.2.,PHPeclipse 1.2.4 and Aptana Studio 3.4.1. on windows 7, I wanted to use the validation function for some xml files. However, I could not find the validate command in my right-click menu.

Looking at my Windows/preferences menu, I could not find any Xml tab, neither (normally under Team).

As an Eclipse newbie, I concluded the xml tools were not correctly installed and try to find a way to install them manually (e.g. as a plugin). However, after looking around eclipse.org and googling a while, I could not find any simple way to do so. I might be wrong but it seems that lots of people consider xml tools as available by default with the eclipse standard package.

Un- and re-installing eclipse (juno and Kepler version x64)  does not change the above issue.

Could anyone help me or point me to the right direction in order to solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Phil

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse SDK is a legacy package primarily used by developers working on Eclipse or Eclipse Plugins. It doesn't include much beyond Java Development Tools and Plugin Development Environment. XML Tools are not included in that package.

You will find a smoother path if you start with one of the higher-level packages.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Having said that, you can add XML Tools into your existing Kepler installation by using the following online plugins repository.

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/

Use the above URL in the install additional software wizard that you will find under your Help menu. Once you see the repository listing, just search for XML.